# Install php site with database on localhost also working via tablet

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, tablet

I have made a "live chat" php website with a database (MySQL) using phpadmin. This is for an organisation that tutors students over chat. The tutors visit the admin panel on their tablet so they can walk around and the students visit the user panel on the pc in the same classroom. Whenever the students have a question the tutors receive a notification. However, out of privacy and security reasons they only want to use it locally without any info going through the worldwide internet. They already have a virtual machine installed.

How am I able to install my php site with database funtion on their localhost also being accessable via tablet? If somebody can just point me in the right direction I think I'll figure it out.

Comment: Whats *They already have a virtual machine installed.* mean? Onsite server? If so install it in there, then requests won't hit the worldwide internets.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm not sure either but it's not VirtualBox or something, it's a VM made by Citrix.